# Chart.js scale x values

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I would to scale the x axis of a chart (displayed using chartjs 2.9).

Below is the script for the chart:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: xvalues,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Absorbance',
      backgroundColor: '#708090',
      borderColor: 'black',
      data: [],
      lineTension: 0,   
      fill: false,
    }]
  },
  options: {
        scales: {
         xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               userCallback: function(item, index) {
                  if (!(index % 9)) return item;
               },
               autoSkip: false
            }
         }],         
         yAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Absorbance'
                        }
                    }]       
         },
        animation: {
            duration: 0 
        },
        hover: {
            animationDuration: 0 
        },
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        responsiveAnimationDuration: 0 
    }
});
```

Every xx seconds, I update the chart like this (the `arrR` is an array that contains all y values). The x values are not given and therefore represent the iteration numbers.

```
 chart.data.datasets[0].data.push(arrR[iteration]); 
    chart.update();
```

I would like to change the scaling like this (see image, where there is a scaling factor of 10):

[image]

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could define `xAxes.ticks.stepSize: 10` as follows:

```
options: {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        min: 1,
        max: 45,
        stepSize: 10
      }
    }]
  }    
}
```

> Please consult the chapter [Tick Options](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/radial/linear.html#tick-options) from the Chart.js documentation.

Comment: Thanks but that it is not I want. I would like 1 to become 10, 10 to become 100. So multiply iteration numbers by 10.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

You can do

```
const xvalues0 = Array.from({length: n}, (_, index) => index + 1);
const xvalues = xvalues0.map(x => x * (timeinterval/(1000*60)));
```